# Combined Plot of a loop

Tags: plotting, procedural-programming

I want this program to plot to be combined into one plot - just can't seem to make it appear in one plot. Any suggestions?

```
n = -1; While[n < 3, 
sol = NDSolve[{D[xtraj[t], 
  t] == -(Sinh[
     2 xtraj[t] (-t + 2)]/ 
      (Cosh[2 xtraj[t] (-t + 2)])), xtraj[0] == n}, 
xtraj[t], {t, -4, 8}]; n = n + 0.25; 
p = ParametricPlot[{t, xtraj[t]} /. sol, {t, -4, 8}, 
PlotRange -> All, PlotStyle -> {Blue, Full, Thick}, 
AxesStyle -> Thickness[.001], LabelStyle -> {Black, Medium}]; 
Print[p]]
```

Comment: Hello! Usually procedural programming is not the go-to tool when using *Mathematica*. More often than not problems can be solved using the functional paradigm of programming. Read the docs on [`ParametricNDSolve`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ParametricNDSolve.html), [`ParametricNDSolveValue`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ParametricNDSolveValue.html), [`Table`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Table.html) and [`Evaluate`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Evaluate.html)

Comment: Welp, since Bill already showed you one solution -- here's another one`pfun = ParametricNDSolveValue[{D[f[t], 
     t] == -(Sinh[2 f[t] (-t + 2)]/(Cosh[2 f[t] (-t + 2)])), 
   f[0] == n}, f, {t, -4, 8}, {n}]; Plot[Evaluate[Table[pfun[n][t], {n, -1, 3, .25}]], {t, 0, 5}, 
 PlotRange -> All]`

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
Show[Table[
  sol = NDSolve[{D[xtraj[t],t] == -(Sinh[2 xtraj[t] (-t + 2)]/
    (Cosh[2 xtraj[t] (-t + 2)])), xtraj[0] == n},xtraj[t], {t, -4, 8}];
  ParametricPlot[{t, xtraj[t]} /. sol, {t, -4, 8}, 
    PlotRange -> All, PlotStyle -> {Blue, Full, Thick}, 
    AxesStyle -> Thickness[.001], LabelStyle -> {Black, Medium}],
  {n,-1,3-1/4,1/4}]]
```

Comment: Thank you! That works nicely, I have used Show[p1,p2..] etc, but didnt think of using it in this way.